# Update the values of a single column in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a table in SQL with 2 columns:

```
ID, Date
```

Then I had to add another, column, "Description", that can be NULL. So my table will look like:

```
ID.     Date.     Description
01.  2000/08/07.     NULL
02.  2000/03/01.     NULL
03.  2001/08/17.     NULL
..
99   2002/12/12.     NULL
```

I have to update the column "Description" with a csv file.

I can't delete this table and each row should have a description

Is there a way to do that in workbench?

The final result should be:

```
ID.     Date.     Description
01.  2000/08/07.     XY
02.  2000/03/01.     XYZ
03.  2001/08/17.     ZY
..
99   2002/12/12.     ZX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the CSV file into a table, using `load data infile`.  Presumably, the file has an `id` to link it to the existing data.  Then use `join`:

```
update t join
       csv_table c
       on t.id = c.id
    set t.description = c.description;
```

Comment: In my case using MariaDB within phpMyAdmin, worked fine when I declared the t table. `update mytable t join csv_table c on t.id = c.id set t.description = c.description;`

Answer (score 0):

Import your csv as a table i.e. table-1. This table should have atleast one common column having distinct values as of the table you mentioned above. Then on the basis of joining, you may update your table for description attribute.

Comment: how is this answer supposed to add anything to the answer already provided?

Comment: Dear Lelilo Faieta, you are right.Actually, i did not see the answer, you are referring.